# Find the coefficient of $x^3$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2)^3$ using Binomial theorem.

Tags: binomial-theorem

Find the coefficient of $x^3$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2)^3$
using Binomial theorem.

Comment: What did you get as a result of $(a+b)^3$? Why couldn't you solve?

Comment: This is small enough polynomial that you can just brute force it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every term in the expansion is the result of the product of the three terms $1,x,x^2$ with some exponents and we can achieve $x^3$ as

$$1^0\,x^3\,(x^2)^0\text{ or }1^0\,x^1\,(x^2)^1.$$

These terms appear with counts given by the multinomial coefficient, and

$$n=\frac{3!}{0!\,3\,!0!}+\frac{3!}{0!\,1!\,1!}=7.$$

---

For information,

$$(1+x+x^2)^3=x^6+3x^5+6x^4+7x^3+6x^2+3x+1.$$

Comment: Can't we solve it by general term method?

Comment: @user608779: what is the "general term method" ?

Comment: Finding its general term

Comment: @user608779: this would be difficult and overkill. The above solution goes straight to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For $x\ne1,$ $$(1+x+x^2)^3=\left(\dfrac{1-x^3}{1-x}\right)^3=(1-x^3)^3(1-x)^{-3}$$

Now use [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) to find the coefficient of $x^3$ to  be

$1\cdot$the coefficient of $x^3$ in $(1-x)^{-3}-3\cdot$the coefficient of $x^{3-3}$ in $(1-x)^{-3}$

$$=1\cdot\dfrac{(-3)(-3-1)(-3-2)}{3!}(-1)^3-3\cdot1=\dfrac{3\cdot4\cdot5}{1\cdot2\cdot3}-3$$

Comment: Isn't that more work than direct computation would involve ? Maybe you didn't say enough.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, We are interested in $x^3$ right? Only two terms can contain $x^3$

Comment: IMO, you should elaborate, this won't be obvious to the OP.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Thanks for tour feedback

Answer (score 0):

Espress it as a product of three brackets:
$$(1+x+x^2)^3=(\underbrace{1+x+x^2}_{{x^i}})(\underbrace{1+x+x^2}_{{x^j}})(\underbrace{1+x+x^2}_{{x^k}})$$
Note that $i+j+k=3$. The possible triples $(i,j,k)$ are:
$$(0,1,2),(0,2,1),(1,0,2),(1,2,0),(2,0,1),(2,1,0),(1,1,1).$$
Hence, the coefficient of $x^3$ is $7$.